# How to get return value (value type is Ext.Net.Panel) from DirectMethod in javascript and add it to a Ext.Net.TabPanel?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ext.net

Ext.net v2.2
.Net Framework v4.5
My Direct Method

```
[DirectMethod]  
   public static Panel AddTab(int postId)  
   {  
       var pnlEditPost = new Panel  
       {  
           ID = postId.ToString(),  
           Icon = Icon.BookEdit,  
           Title = "Edit",  
           Layout = "Fit",  
           Closable = true,  
           AutoDoLayout = true  
       };  
       return pnlEditPost;  
   }
```

I need get the pnlEditPost in javascript and add it to my TabPanel

Comment: `TabPanel.Tabs.Add(AddTab(id));` might work (but i have no idea if it works exactly that way ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact answer is no way to return a Panel instance.

But you can return a string with a Panel's config.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Ext.Net" Namespace="Ext.Net" TagPrefix="ext" %>

<script runat="server">
    [DirectMethod]
    public static string AddTab(int count)
    {
        return ComponentLoader.ToConfig(new Ext.Net.Panel
        {
            Title = "Tab " + count,
            Html = "Server time: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()
        });
    }
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Ext.NET v2 Example</title>

    <script>
        var addTab = function () {
            var tabPanel = App.TabPanel1;

            App.direct.AddTab(tabPanel.items.getCount(), {
                success: function (result) {
                    var tabs = tabPanel.add(eval(result));

                    tabPanel.setActiveTab(tabs[0]);
                }
            });
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <ext:ResourceManager runat="server" />

        <ext:Button runat="server" Text="Add tab" Handler="addTab" />

        <ext:TabPanel ID="TabPanel1" runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Also you might be interested to look at [this example](http://examples.ext.net/#/Loaders/Component/Direct_Method/).

Comment: thanks for your answer, please guide me how to write success handler in Javascript. I want to add this panel to my TabPanel

Comment: I have edited the answer adding a full example. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast response, actually this works for a simple panel, but in my program I need to add portlet, portal column and etc to my panel; and ComponentLoader.ToConfig doesn`t work for them

Comment: It looks a candidate for a new question.